# spring-integration csv file into json file

Tags: json, csv, spring-integration

I am trying to convert a csv file into JSON using Spring Integration but I could not find the suitable command in the xml file

I have csv file with header for example

```
empID, empName, dateOfBirth, Salary
1, Alice, 1990-05-14, 1000
2, Bob, 1991-06-15, 1100
3, Charlie, 1992-07-16, 1500
```

will become:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Alice",
    "dateOfBirth": "1990-05-14",
    "Salary": 1000
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Bob",
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-06-15",
    "Salary": 1100
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Charlie",
    "dateOfBirth": "1992-07-16",
    "Salary": 1500
  }
]
```

notice in the way i have also done some header name mapping "empID" become "ID" and "empName" become  "Name"

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look to the Spring Batch `FlatFileItemReader`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#flatFiles

> A flat file is any type of file that contains at most two-dimensional (tabular) data. Reading flat files in the Spring Batch framework is facilitated by the class called `FlatFileItemReader`, which provides basic functionality for reading and parsing flat files. The two most important required dependencies of `FlatFileItemReader` are `Resource` and `LineMapper`.

You can use it from the `<int:transformer>`.

When you done with this you can simply use `<int:object-to-json-transformer>` to generate a JSON based on the intermediate POJO or just `Map` returned from that `transformer` based on the `FlatFileItemReader`.